# how to convert TimeUnit to seconds or hours?

Tags: android

I want to convert TimeUnit to seconds or hours , I've asked a lot but do not get a satisfactory answer.
I've read on     http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toHours(long) but I don't understand to use
example:

```
String strfileDate = "2012-04-19 15:15:00";
 DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date da =formatter2.parse(strFileDate);
        long diffInMs = da.getTime() - new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();
        long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMs);
```

I want to convert valuse of "diffInSec" to Seconds, hours

Comment: Can you give some more context about what you are trying to achieve?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines.

Comment: Please provide some example input and desired output you want and example codes that you've tried.

Comment: Why not just use the diffInMs and multiply it with the correct values. For example diffInMs / 1000 = seconds?

Answer (score 5):

convert day to hours, should be `TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(days)`.
for other type, change Enum value for source time unit.